Does Sorting Rows Minimize the Sum of Differences from Column Minimums in a Matrix
I'm working with an $m$ x $n$ matrix $A$ where each cell $A_{r,c}$ (where r is the row and c is the column of the matrix) contains a numerical value. My goal is to minimize the sum over all columns the sum of the differences between each value in a column($A_{r,c=i}$) and the minimum value of that column($\min_{c=i}$). The values within each row are allowed to be rearranged in any order, but they must remain within their original row.
$$\min_{\sigma_1,...,\sigma_m\in S_n}\sum_{c}\sum_{r}\left({{\text{A}}_{r,\sigma_r(c)}-{\min (A_{1,\sigma_1(c)},...,A_{m,\sigma_m(c)})}}\right)$$
I have written a constraint program to do this, but I have noticed that if I sort the rows of the matrix in ascending order, the sum of the sum of the differences between each element and the minimum value in its respective column seems to provide the same minimum solution.
For example, the following matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
90 & 76 & 75 & 70 & 50 & 74 & 12 & 68 \\
35 & 85 & 55 & 65 & 48 & 101 & 70 & 83 \\
125 & 95 & 90 & 105 & 59 & 120 & 36 & 73 \\
45 & 110 & 95 & 115 & 104 & 83 & 37 & 71 \\
60 & 105 & 80 & 75 & 59 & 62 & 93 & 88 \\
45 & 65 & 110 & 95 & 47 & 31 & 81 & 34 \\
38 & 51 & 107 & 41 & 69 & 99 & 115 & 48 \\
47 & 85 & 57 & 71 & 92 & 77 & 109 & 36 \\
39 & 63 & 97 & 49 & 118 & 56 & 92 & 61 \\
47 & 101 & 71 & 60 & 88 & 109 & 52 & 90 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}221 + 326 + 287 + 336 + 264 + 502 + 577 + 312\end{bmatrix}
so the first column min is 35, so sum up (90-35) + (35-35) + (125-35) ... + (47-35) to give the first columnar sum as 221. Do this for each column then sum all of these sums together which in this case is 2,825
when run through the constraint program to permute the values within each row:
\begin{bmatrix}
12 & 74 & 50 & 68 & 70 & 90 & 76 & 75 \\
48 & 55 & 70 & 35 & 65 & 101 & 83 & 85 \\
73 & 59 & 95 & 36 & 90 & 105 & 125 & 120 \\
37 & 110 & 83 & 45 & 71 & 95 & 104 & 115 \\
88 & 60 & 62 & 59 & 80 & 93 & 105 & 75 \\
31 & 45 & 47 & 34 & 65 & 95 & 110 & 81 \\
41 & 48 & 51 & 38 & 69 & 115 & 107 & 99 \\
47 & 71 & 57 & 36 & 77 & 109 & 92 & 85 \\
39 & 56 & 61 & 49 & 63 & 118 & 92 & 97 \\
52 & 71 & 60 & 47 & 88 & 109 & 101 & 90 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}348 + 199 + 166 + 107 + 108 + 130 + 235 + 172\end{bmatrix}
with an optimum value of 1,465
But sorting the rows in ascending order results in the following:
\begin{bmatrix}
12 & 50 & 68 & 70 & 74 & 75 & 76 & 90 \\
35 & 48 & 55 & 65 & 70 & 83 & 85 & 101 \\
36 & 59 & 73 & 90 & 95 & 105 & 120 & 125 \\
37 & 45 & 71 & 83 & 95 & 104 & 110 & 115 \\
59 & 60 & 62 & 75 & 80 & 88 & 93 & 105 \\
31 & 34 & 45 & 47 & 65 & 81 & 95 & 110 \\
38 & 41 & 48 & 51 & 69 & 99 & 107 & 115 \\ 
36 & 47 & 57 & 71 & 77 & 85 & 92 & 109 \\
39 & 49 & 56 & 61 & 63 & 92 & 97 & 118 \\
47 & 52 & 60 & 71 & 88 & 90 & 101 & 109 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}250 + 145 + 145 + 214 + 146 + 152 + 216 + 197\end{bmatrix}
With the same value of 1,465
This is just 1 of many examples I have run across.
My question is:
Does sorting the rows actually guarantee a minimized sum of differences from the column minimums?
If so, is there a mathematical proof or a known theorem that supports this observation?
Any insights or guidance on a mathematical approach to prove (or disprove) this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

A little formalism setup wouldn't hurt: Start by naming the matrix (e.g. $A$), then define some notation for selecting a column of $A$ (e.g. let $A_{\downarrow i}$ denote the $i$-th column of $A$). Then rewrite your first formula, and also make explicit in it, which is the variable over which you minimize.

@ConnFus - Thanks for the feedback. Added some formalism. Let me know if additional info is needed.

I'm still confused as to what exactly you are trying to minimize. All parts in your minimization problem seem to be fixed. Are you minimizing over a set of allowed transformations which you apply beforehand to the matrix?

OK - I see that was not very clear now. Yes - the values within a row can be permuted in order to minimize the sum of the sums of each of the values in a particular column minus the minimum of that column. So the if a particular value say $A_{0,6}$ is swapped with another value in the same row say $A_{0,0}$ the column differences between the minimums will change. The goal is to permute values in each row to minimize this columnar sum of differences. I hope that is clearer.

Then the objects you're minimizing over are elements of the set $S_n$, the set of all permutations ${1,...,n}\to {1,...,n}$. So, to formulate it as mostly self-sufficient formula, I think what you're looking for is$$
\min_{\sigma_1,...,\sigma_m\in S_n}\sum_{c}\sum_{r}\left({{\text{A}}{r,\sigma_r(c)}-{\min (A{1,\sigma_1(c)},...,A_{m,\sigma_m(c)})}}\right)
$$

Thanks @ConnFus - Updated minimization equation

Let $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_m\in S_n$ be fixed but arbitrary.
Then
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{c}\sum_{r}\left({{\text{A}}_{r,\sigma_r(c)}-{\min (A_{1,\sigma_1(c)},...,A_{m,\sigma_m(c)})}}\right)
\\
=&\underbrace{\left(\sum_{c}\sum_{r}{{\text{A}}_{r,\sigma_r(c)}}\right)}_{=:C}
-
\left(\sum_{c}\sum_{r}\min (A_{1,\sigma_1(c)},...,A_{m,\sigma_m(c)})\right)
\\
=&C
-
m\sum_{c}\min (A_{1,\sigma_1(c)},...,A_{m,\sigma_m(c)})\end{align}
$$
So all that matters is that you choose your permutations $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_m$ such that the sum of the minima gets as big as possible. We'll call that sum of the minima our 'target function'.
With this now sorting starts to make sense: Because if a column contains both a big and a small entry, then the big entry is more or less wasted.
Now let $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_m$ be chosen optimally (i.e. such that they maximize the target function). Let $A$ denote the matrix $A$ after we applied our permutations. Assume the minimal entries of each row of $A$ aren't all in the same column of $A$.
Then there exist two columns with indices $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $A_{r_1,c_1}$ is the minimal element of row $r_1$, and $A_{r_2,c_2}$ is the minimal element of row $r_2$.
Let wlog $A_{r_1,c_1}\le A_{r_2,c_2}$. Then swapping $A_{r_2,c_2}$ and $A_{r_2,c_1}$ can only increase the value of the target function.
We can repeat the process till the minimal entries of each row of $A$
are all in the same column of $A$, and in each step, the value of the target function is increasing or stays constant.
Then we repeat the process for the second smallest entries of each row, then the third smallest of each row, and so on.
In the end we arrive at a matrix, which is, up to a permutation of its columns which does not affect the value of the target function, the matrix in which each row was sorted in ascending order.
This then shows that sorting each row of $A$ in ascending order is a minimizer to our original  minimization problem.

Thanks @ConnFus. It made sense to me intuitively, I just couldn't mathematically put it together. Thanks for the clear explanation
